# ProgressDialog saindo (dismiss) antes da execução do código anterior

Tags: java, android

Boa Tarde Pessoal!

Fiz uma tela de pedidos, onde basicamente há um looping alimentado por um vetor de dados do WS, onde ele vai incluindo as "linhas" no linearlayout.
Durante esse processo, eu exibo um ProgressDialog e o mesmo é finalizado após a inclusão das linhas.
**O problema é que o loader é finalizado e as linhas aparecem todas de uma só vez**
Segue o trecho do código:

```
        Vector<SoapObject> soAssinaturas = (Vector<SoapObject>) sobj.getProperty("assinaturas");
    for (int i = 0; i < soAssinaturas.size(); i++) {


        //INSTANCIA OS TEXTVIEW
        final String txtPedido =signBox.getDocumento();

        final View assinaturasb = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.assinaturabox, null);
        final TextView orcamento = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.orcamento);
        final TextView sign1 = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.sign1);
        final TextView sign2 = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.sign2);
        final TextView empresa = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.empresa);
        final TextView valor = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.valor);
        final TextView data = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.data);
        final TextView pedido = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.pedido);
        final TextView tipoDoc = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.tipoDoc);
        final CheckBox ckb = assinaturasb.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US).parse(signBox.getData_entrega().subSequence(0,10).toString());
        String form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.US).format(date);

        String lang = "";
        String coun= "";
        switch(signBox.getMoeda().trim()){
            case "R$":lang="pt";coun="BR";break;
            case "JPY":lang="ja";coun="JP";break;
            case "EUR":lang="es";coun="ES";break;
            default:lang="pt";coun="BR";break;
        }
        //MOEDA
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(signBox.getValor());
        Locale ptBr = new Locale(lang, coun);
        String valorString = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(ptBr).format(d);
        valor.setText(valorString);

        //PEGA APENAS A PRIMEIRA LINHA DO PROJETO PARA EXIBIR
        String[] projeto = signBox.getTexto().split("\r\n|\r|\n", 2);
        empresa.setText(projeto[0].toUpperCase().replace("CUSTOMER:","").trim());//PROJETO (campo texto)
        pedido.setText(signBox.getPedido());
        tipoDoc.setText(signBox.getTipo_documento());
        data.setText(form.toString());
        orcamento.setText(signBox.getOrcamento());

        ckb.setEnabled(false);
        sign2.setText("AGUARDANDO");
        sign1.setText("AGUARDANDO");






        containerAssinaturas.addView(assinaturasb,0);



    }
    load.dismiss();
```

Comment: Para esse propósito, seria interessante você usar uma `View` de lista, pois dependendo do tamanho dos seus dados, você pode levar um belo `OutOfMemory`. Use o `RecyclerView` que é mais apropriado.

Comment: @IvanSilva Obrigado pela sugestão , vou implementar em uma RecyclerView. Mas será que resolvera o problema?

Comment: De forma resumida, se você quer uma linha aparecendo por veze, precisará criar uma animação pra isso ou você pode utilizar uma lib de terceiros para animações em `RecyclerView`. Veja o que consegue, e qualquer erro é só abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @IvanSilva em relação ao ProgressDialog sair antes do carregamento dos itens na UI, seria algum problema de thread ?

Comment: Poste o código que você já tem. Assim que eu chegar eu olho

Comment: @IvanSilva Implementei o recyclerview conforme sua sugestão e solucionou todos os problemas. Muito obrigado!! :D

Comment: De nada. Fico feliz em ter ajudado!